# Set random days on users with Date in Java?

Tags: java, date, localdate

I have for example 30 users and for everyone i want to set vacation with random start_day and random end_day of vacation. I want to use Date, not LocalDate. If i must do with LocalDate this is the answer.

```
LocalDate date = LocalDate.now();

 List<VacationUser> collectVacationUser = allVacationUsers.stream()
      .map(user -> {
         if (inVacation()) {
            return new VacationUser(date.minusDays(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 5)),
                                        date.plusDays(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(1, 5)));
         } else {
            return new VacationUser(user.getPrimaryEmail());
         }
       }).collect(toList());
        return collectVacationUser;
    }
```

I want to do this with Date, because in JSON date format with 'Date' is this "yyyy/mm/dd", in the other hand if I use LocalDate a format in JSON is something like this

```
"year":2018,"month":"AUGUST","era":"CE","dayOfMonth":16,"dayOfWeek":"THURSDAY","dayOfYear":228,"leapYear":false,"monthValue":8,"chronology":{"id":"ISO","calendarType":"iso8601"
```

Comment: You are changing the Date class because the JSON format comes out right. The better approach is to see how you can configure your JSON formatter so that it formats LocalDate differently. Are you using org.json.JSONObject? Can you instead use Gson or Jackson libraries?

Comment: If you still want to do this, you can use java.util.Date by using java.util.Calendar for date arithmetic.

Comment: While the conversion from `LocalDate` to `Date` goes through a number of steps, it’s not hard.

Comment: I don’t know which tool you are using for creating your JSON, but there are ways to produce JSON output like `yyyy/MM/dd` or (ISO 8601) `yyyy-MM-dd` from `LocalDate`. Use your search engine. I believe this will be a better solution than falling back on the outdated class.

Comment: Seriously: you are confusing stuff. You shouldnt ask how to do that with Date objects, but you should ask how to properly format a LocalDate as JSON.

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

- Use types appropriate to your values: `LocalDate`
- Never use the terrible legacy class `java.util.Date`
- Learn to use converters/adapters in your Java⇔JSON serialization framework
- Use standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats for date-time values whenever possible

## Details

Use appropriate types to represent your data values. For a date-only value, without a time-of-day and without a time zone, the appropriate type is `LocalDate`.

Never use `java.util.Date`. That terrible class was supplanted years ago by the *java.time* classes.

As for generating textual representations in JSON, that is an entirely separate issue.

JSON has very few data types and none of them are date-time related. So whatever JSON output you are getting for your `LocalDate` input is a function of your particular Java-to-JSON library you are using. You do not divulge what library, so we cannot provide further assistance.

I can tell you that there is an established practical international standard for representing date-time values: [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). I strongly suggest always using these standard formats when serializing your date-time values to text.

For a date-only value, the standard format is YYYY-MM-DD such as `2018-01-23`.

The *java.time* classes use these standard formats by default when parsing/generating strings.

```
LocalDate.parse( "2018-01-23" ) ;
```

And:

```
myLocalDate.toString()
```

> 2018-01-23

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Comment: But, how can i do this in my code. My example is : I have date.now(), which return me data for today ( 16/08/2018 ) , if i run tomorow this it return me ( 17/08/2018 ) ... and in my lambda i set random data for start day ( from today to random minus 1 - 5 days) and end day ( from today to random plus 1 - 5 days). In my datebase for column startdate,enddate type is TIMESTAMP. How can use LocalDate.now() with your example. Thanks for answer :)

Comment: @BRRusev (A)  `date.now()` does not return a date, it returns a date-time in UTC. When you say "run tomorrow" that would be tomorrow according to UTC, not tomorrow in your own time zone. (B) Now in this comment you are talking about moments (`TIMESTAMP` in database) but your Question only talks about dates, not date-with-time. If you edit your Question to get **very specific** about your details, then maybe I can edit my Answer. But I cannot keep on guessing as you change your story. Please put more care and effort into drafting your Question so as to not waste our time here.

Comment: Тhank you for helping with the answer above I've fixed myself end all is ok :)